# TYPO3 does not notice changes from local extension installed via composer

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-9.x

I've created a local extension and then installed it via composer.

```
composer require vendorname/extension_key:@dev
```

Everything works as expected.

The Problem is, when I change the code of some file for example some css or a HTML teamplte file, TYPO3 does not notice the changes.

I've tried the following:

- Clearing the Caches
- composer update command
- composer require command
- composer dumpautoload

If I update or require the extension again, then to composer tells me "Nothing to install or update".

The only thing that does work if I remove the extension via composer remove and

```
composer remove vendorname/extension_key
```

then then add it again with composer require.

```
composer require vendorname/extension_key:@dev
```

Is there a better way to do this, because this is slow and inefficient.

Comment: The autoloading is only affecting PHP classes. If your Template or CSS file changes are without any effects I think this is not caused by composer. Are you sure, that you edit the correct files which are used by the TYPO3 system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the "version" property of the chomposer.json of the extension.

When I made a change then I changed the version number to the next higher number.

Example: `"version": "1.0.1"` to `"version": "1.0.2"`

Then I ran the composer command:

```
composer update vendorname/extension_key
```

The composer realized that there is a new version and installs it. TYPO3 then notices all the changes and everything works.

Not sure if this is the best way, but it works the best for me so far.

I hope this is helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

In general; it is not expected that an extension changes. And for performance a lot of files are cached in TYPO3. This includes PHP files but also CSS and JS files (compression and concatenation)

So if you change a file all caches for this file needs to be invalidated.

If you run your installation in debug/ development mode the usage of caches is reduced drastically.

On deactivating and reactivating an extension the caches for all files in that extension are refreshed.

After each change you either could clear all relevant caches: if you know them, you can do it by hand or you use the core possibilities (one is the extension manager, but don't forget the commandline tool).

---

on dev installations I would prefer debug mode without much php caches, and without concatenation and compression for CSS and JS.